# PJSIP syntax error exception when parsing

Tags: java, android, asterisk, pjsip

My PJSUA2 example is returning the following:

```
11:31:41.606 sip_transport.  Error processing 575 bytes packet from UDP 0.0.0.0:5060 : PJSIP syntax error exception when parsing 'To' header on line 5 col 38:
```

and I'm already out of ideas.

Asterisk does register the client, but two seconds later it retuns:

```
[Jul  2 10:35:16] NOTICE[29444]: chan_sip.c:29614 sip_poke_noanswer: Peer 'cli_id' is now UNREACHABLE!  Last qualify: 0
```

Complete registration log:

```
07-02 11:36:19.216: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): LW(4) Msg: 11:36:19.216    pjsua_acc.c !Modifying account 0
07-02 11:36:19.216: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): LW(4) Msg: 11:36:19.216    pjsua_acc.c  .Acc 0: setting registration..
07-02 11:36:19.218: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): LW(4) Msg: 11:36:19.218   pjsua_core.c  ...TX 540 bytes Request msg REGISTER/cseq=36362 (tdta0xb8f4b318) to UDP 0.0.0.0:5060:
07-02 11:36:19.218: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): REGISTER sip:0.0.0.0 SIP/2.0

07-02 11:36:19.218: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 177.18.138.40:6000;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPj8Zgyj-VhRy7k.HUYrXplLPJTwczF4hWd

07-02 11:36:19.218: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): Max-Forwards: 70

07-02 11:36:19.218: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): From: <sip:cli_id@0.0.0.0>;tag=wXhCUdH83Sppgh6r1LRSskgsXMvvi1sE

07-02 11:36:19.218: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): To: <sip:cli_id@0.0.0.0>

07-02 11:36:19.218: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): Call-ID: kP216wpZXD.jfVC1wfPfu7FX.ZKKkRBm

07-02 11:36:19.218: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): CSeq: 36362 REGISTER

07-02 11:36:19.218: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): User-Agent: Pjsua2 Android 2.4

07-02 11:36:19.218: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): Contact: <sip:cli_id@177.18.138.40:6000;ob>;+sip.ice

07-02 11:36:19.218: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): Expires: 300

07-02 11:36:19.218: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS

07-02 11:36:19.218: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): Content-Length:  0

07-02 11:36:19.218: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): 

07-02 11:36:19.218: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): --end msg--
07-02 11:36:19.221: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): LW(4) Msg: 11:36:19.221    pjsua_acc.c  ..Acc 0: Registration sent
07-02 11:36:19.221: I/PJSUA2 (Main)(6350): printAccountInfo() -> Account válida! 
07-02 11:36:19.221: I/PJSUA2 (Main)(6350): printAccountInfo() -> getId: 0
07-02 11:36:19.221: I/PJSUA2 (Main)(6350): printAccountInfo() -> getOnlineStatusText: Offline
07-02 11:36:19.221: I/PJSUA2 (Main)(6350): printAccountInfo() -> getRegExpiresSec: 0
07-02 11:36:19.221: I/PJSUA2 (Main)(6350): printAccountInfo() -> getRegLastErr: 0
07-02 11:36:19.221: I/PJSUA2 (Main)(6350): printAccountInfo() -> getRegStatusText: OK
07-02 11:36:19.224: I/PJSUA2 (Main)(6350): printAccountInfo() -> getUri: sip:cli_id@0.0.0.0
07-02 11:36:19.224: I/PJSUA2 (Main)(6350): printAccountInfo() -> getOnlineStatus: false
07-02 11:36:19.224: I/PJSUA2 (Main)(6350): printAccountInfo() -> getRegIsActive: false
07-02 11:36:19.227: I/PJSUA2 (Main)(6350): printAccountInfo() -> getRegIsConfigured: true
07-02 11:36:19.228: I/PJSUA2 (Main)(6350): printAccountInfo() -> getRegStatus: PJSIP_SC_OK
07-02 11:36:19.407: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): LW(4) Msg: 11:36:19.405   pjsua_core.c !.RX 586 bytes Response msg 401/REGISTER/cseq=36362 (rdata0xb8dd676c) from UDP 0.0.0.0:5060:
07-02 11:36:19.407: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized

07-02 11:36:19.407: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.25.7:6000;branch=z9hG4bKPj8Zgyj-VhRy7k.HUYrXplLPJTwczF4hWd;received=177.18.138.40;rport=6000

07-02 11:36:19.407: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): From: <sip:cli_id@0.0.0.0>;tag=wXhCUdH83Sppgh6r1LRSskgsXMvvi1sE

07-02 11:36:19.407: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): To: <sip:cli_id@0.0.0.0>;tag=as102feee0

07-02 11:36:19.407: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): Call-ID: kP216wpZXD.jfVC1wfPfu7FX.ZKKkRBm

07-02 11:36:19.407: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): CSeq: 36362 REGISTER

07-02 11:36:19.407: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): Server: Asterisk PBX 11.16.0

07-02 11:36:19.407: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE

07-02 11:36:19.407: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): Supported: replaces, timer

07-02 11:36:19.407: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): WWW-Authenticate: Digest algorithm=MD5, realm="0.0.0.0", nonce="61d61816"

07-02 11:36:19.407: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): Content-Length: 0

07-02 11:36:19.407: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): 

07-02 11:36:19.407: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): --end msg--
07-02 11:36:19.408: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): LW(4) Msg: 11:36:19.407   pjsua_core.c  ....TX 711 bytes Request msg REGISTER/cseq=36363 (tdta0xb8f4b318) to UDP 0.0.0.0:5060:
07-02 11:36:19.408: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): REGISTER sip:0.0.0.0 SIP/2.0

07-02 11:36:19.408: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 177.18.138.40:6000;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPj7wWNB5U9PDaphvFHGvOHeXbY6Pc4EHxn

07-02 11:36:19.408: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): Max-Forwards: 70

07-02 11:36:19.408: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): From: <sip:cli_id@0.0.0.0>;tag=wXhCUdH83Sppgh6r1LRSskgsXMvvi1sE

07-02 11:36:19.408: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): To: <sip:cli_id@0.0.0.0>

07-02 11:36:19.408: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): Call-ID: kP216wpZXD.jfVC1wfPfu7FX.ZKKkRBm

07-02 11:36:19.408: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): CSeq: 36363 REGISTER

07-02 11:36:19.408: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): User-Agent: Pjsua2 Android 2.4

07-02 11:36:19.408: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): Contact: <sip:cli_id@177.18.138.40:6000;ob>;+sip.ice

07-02 11:36:19.408: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): Expires: 300

07-02 11:36:19.408: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS

07-02 11:36:19.408: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): Authorization: Digest username="cli_id", realm="0.0.0.0", nonce="61d61816", uri="sip:0.0.0.0", response="a0bf36ad494dc508637536a00810648c", algorithm=MD5

07-02 11:36:19.408: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): Content-Length:  0

07-02 11:36:19.408: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): 

07-02 11:36:19.408: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): --end msg--
07-02 11:36:19.621: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): LW(1) Msg: 11:36:19.618 sip_transport.  Error processing 575 bytes packet from UDP 0.0.0.0:5060 : PJSIP syntax error exception when parsing 'To' header on line 5 col 38:
07-02 11:36:19.621: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): OPTIONS sip:cli_id@177.18.138.40:6000;ob SIP/2.0

07-02 11:36:19.621: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 0.0.0.0:5060;branch=z9hG4bK625f8cc3

07-02 11:36:19.621: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): Max-Forwards: 70

07-02 11:36:19.621: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): From: "asterisk" <sip:asterisk@0.0.0.0>;tag=as30120c1b

07-02 11:36:19.621: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): To: <sip:cli_id@192.168.25.7:6000>;ob>

07-02 11:36:19.621: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): Contact: <sip:asterisk@0.0.0.0:5060>

07-02 11:36:19.621: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): Call-ID: 18d0ca3800f4a2c9028946a9597af025@0.0.0.0:5060

07-02 11:36:19.621: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): CSeq: 102 OPTIONS

07-02 11:36:19.621: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): User-Agent: Asterisk PBX 11.16.0

07-02 11:36:19.621: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): Date: Thu, 02 Jul 2015 14:36:06 GMT

07-02 11:36:19.621: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE

07-02 11:36:19.621: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): Supported: replaces, timer

07-02 11:36:19.621: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): Content-Length: 0

07-02 11:36:19.621: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): 

07-02 11:36:19.621: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): -- end of packet.
07-02 11:36:19.635: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): LW(4) Msg: 11:36:19.632   pjsua_core.c  .RX 600 bytes Response msg 200/REGISTER/cseq=36363 (rdata0xb8dd676c) from UDP 0.0.0.0:5060:
07-02 11:36:19.635: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): SIP/2.0 200 OK

07-02 11:36:19.635: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.25.7:6000;branch=z9hG4bKPj7wWNB5U9PDaphvFHGvOHeXbY6Pc4EHxn;received=177.18.138.40;rport=6000

07-02 11:36:19.635: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): From: <sip:cli_id@0.0.0.0>;tag=wXhCUdH83Sppgh6r1LRSskgsXMvvi1sE

07-02 11:36:19.635: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): To: <sip:cli_id@0.0.0.0>;tag=as102feee0

07-02 11:36:19.635: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): Call-ID: kP216wpZXD.jfVC1wfPfu7FX.ZKKkRBm

07-02 11:36:19.635: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): CSeq: 36363 REGISTER

07-02 11:36:19.635: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): Server: Asterisk PBX 11.16.0

07-02 11:36:19.635: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE

07-02 11:36:19.635: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): Supported: replaces, timer

07-02 11:36:19.635: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): Expires: 300

07-02 11:36:19.635: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): Contact: <sip:cli_id@192.168.25.7:6000;ob>;expires=300

07-02 11:36:19.635: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): Date: Thu, 02 Jul 2015 14:36:06 GMT

07-02 11:36:19.635: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): Content-Length: 0

07-02 11:36:19.635: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): 

07-02 11:36:19.635: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): --end msg--
07-02 11:36:19.638: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): LW(4) Msg: 11:36:19.636    pjsua_acc.c  ....SIP outbound status for acc 0 is not active
07-02 11:36:19.641: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): LW(3) Msg: 11:36:19.639    pjsua_acc.c  ....sip:cli_id@0.0.0.0: registration success, status=200 (OK), will re-register in 300 seconds
07-02 11:36:19.645: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): LW(4) Msg: 11:36:19.641    pjsua_acc.c  ....Keep-alive timer started for acc 0, destination:0.0.0.0:5060, interval:15s
07-02 11:36:19.646: I/PJSUA2 (MyApp - MyAccount)(6350): onRegState
07-02 11:36:19.646: I/PJSUA2 (Main)(6350): notifyRegState()
07-02 11:36:19.650: I/PJSUA2 (Main)(6350): handleMessage()
07-02 11:36:20.648: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): LW(1) Msg: 11:36:20.645 sip_transport.  Error processing 575 bytes packet from UDP 0.0.0.0:5060 : PJSIP syntax error exception when parsing 'To' header on line 5 col 38:
07-02 11:36:20.648: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): OPTIONS sip:cli_id@177.18.138.40:6000;ob SIP/2.0

07-02 11:36:20.648: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 0.0.0.0:5060;branch=z9hG4bK625f8cc3

07-02 11:36:20.648: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): Max-Forwards: 70

07-02 11:36:20.648: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): From: "asterisk" <sip:asterisk@0.0.0.0>;tag=as30120c1b

07-02 11:36:20.648: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): To: <sip:cli_id@192.168.25.7:6000>;ob>

07-02 11:36:20.648: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): Contact: <sip:asterisk@0.0.0.0:5060>

07-02 11:36:20.648: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): Call-ID: 18d0ca3800f4a2c9028946a9597af025@0.0.0.0:5060

07-02 11:36:20.648: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): CSeq: 102 OPTIONS

07-02 11:36:20.648: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): User-Agent: Asterisk PBX 11.16.0

07-02 11:36:20.648: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): Date: Thu, 02 Jul 2015 14:36:06 GMT

07-02 11:36:20.648: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE

07-02 11:36:20.648: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): Supported: replaces, timer

07-02 11:36:20.648: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): Content-Length: 0

07-02 11:36:20.648: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): 

07-02 11:36:20.648: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(6350): -- end of packet.
```

The " *PJSIP syntax error exception when parsing 'To' header on line 5 col 38* " seems to be in the compiled lib, so I don't know how to debug that, and pretty much no idea of what to do next.

Any suggestions at all are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Line `To: <sip:cli_id@192.168.25.7:6000>;ob>` present in OPTIONS that asterisk is sending is obviously not valid. You can try to disable qualify in asterisk configuration to disable these OPTIONS messages.

Using 0.0.0.0 IP address is at least unusual and can also trigger problems.

Comment: The real IP was replaced by 0.0.0.0 from the LOG before I posted here ^^" (just as the client_id isn't 'cli_id').
The '>;ob>' I did notice, but tought it was a wrong send from my client, because with a SIPML5 client it does works fine. But does make sense asterisk been the one who is doing something diferent, since it is registring the user, just not sending the POKE message. Why asterisk would have diferent behavior with those clients? 
But, I'm gone take a look at that, thanks!

Comment: Oh, you missed few places then with this replacing I think. I'm guessing this asterisk bug is triggered by ob param presence in Contact from pjsua. Search for account config use_rfc5626 parameter or natConfig.sipOutboundUse in pjsua2.